# Inheriting parent's properties in a Javascript child object

Tags: javascript, oop

If I have these 2 functions:

```
function Person(age)
{
   this.setAge = function(newAge)
   {
       age = newAge;
   }

   this.getAge = function()
   {
      alert(age);
   }
}

function Bob(age)
{
    Person.call(this, age);
    this.foo = function() {} //etc
}

Bob.prototype = new Person();

bob = new Bob(43);
bob.getAge();
```

Will the correct age (43) be alerted?

Comment: Yes. Click Upvote. That was not a reference to the OP's username, but a request on my comment.

Comment: This is a silly question. You can test/try this yourself in any browser. Better question would be: why?

Comment: @Rudie because I'm trying to see if there are any pitfalls with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes but calling setAge will not change the foo functions version of age since they are different captured variables. Consider moving to a style that looks more like,

```
function Person(age) { this.age = age; }
Person.prototype.getAge = function() { return this.age; };
Person.prototype.setAge = function(value) { this.age = value; }
function Bob(age) { Person.call(this, age); }
Bob.prototype = new Person();
Bob.prototype.foo = function() { /* ... */ }
```

Note that `foo()` and `getAge()` now see the same value for `this.age`. Also this is *much* more space efficient since the instance of Person and Bob only consume one slot per instance instead of 3 to 4 and do not require closure environments to be created for getAge, setAge and foo.

Comment: @Chucky If I kept `Bob.foo()` inside the function as in my question, and used `this.getAge()` instead of accessing `this.age` directly, will I get the correct value of age?

Comment: Yes. In both examples, if getAge() is changed to return the value instead of alert() in the first example.